# How do I use customized node modules?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I've customized an existing node module and would like for my `node.js` app to use it in production.

Where should I host the forked version of the module?

How do I specify that I would like to use the customized module in my `package.json`?

My production server needs to be able to access the same version I have modified locally in the `node_modules/` directory.

SN: I've tried using Github and pointing to the repo in `package.json`. I ran into several issues before taking a step back and wondering if I was taking the best approach.

`package.json` from Github attempt:

```
 ...

  "dependencies": {
    "express": "3.1.x",
    "crawlme": "git@github.com:DruRly/Crawlme.git"
  },

 ...
```

Comment: How have you specified your GitHub repo in `package.json`? Depending on the format, it should work: https://npmjs.org/doc/cli/npm-install.html

Comment: Thanks @gustavohenke! I had to to prefix the value with `git+ssh://`

Answer (score 0):

Well you can host them @ the [npm repository](https://npmjs.org/) itself. In fact, anyone can and the best thing about it, is that you can just download your own package through `npm install <your package name>`.

To get started, you need to do this like so:

1. Go to your package directory, I see you've already made a `package.json` file there, so thats good, but its a part of the process. Since you've already made it, I won't elaborate
2. Run this command `npm init`
3. Fill out the data it wants. One interesting part is the `point of entry` parameter, make sure you think about it before you put something down.
4. After that, make sure that you have a npm username, if not run `npm adduser` and go through the process
5. Then you simply `npm publish`

You should not be able to search for your module using the module you named it. `npm` has also other functionality, for example when you are making it, you can make a git-hub repo link for where your code is posted.

Now on your host, simply run `npm install <your package name>` and viola, you can use those packages yourself.